# How to add a datasource in BIRT IServer

Tags: birt, actuate

I have downloaded a trial version of Actuates iServer.
I want to try using the "BIRT Studio" designer.

However I cant find how to set up a datasource to connect to the required database.

Note I have used the Eclipse BIRT report designer and created datasources just fine but it in the BIRT IServer application that I cant find where to do it.

All I can see are loads of sample reports and no way of creating a report on MY database...

I'm sure it must be very easy but I just cant find it!

Answer (score 0):

BIRT Studio requires an existing Information Object or Data Object in order to create a report.  Both of these can be created in BIRT Designer Professional then migrated to the iServer.